# Python sort list by regular expression

Tags: python, regex, string, list, sorting

I have a list of strings looking like this:

```
['dsafjhsafjkhefhajwejh;NR;123;dfgdsrhgjhdfgjhdsfjhg','jhfewrgjhdfjhgsufgssdfjgh;NR;3243;fgjdsgfjsdfkjgdf', ...]
```

This list should be sorted by the numbers in between the ";", the numbers always come after ";NR;", but not every string contains a number. I've already tried hundreds of solutions and none seems to work.

Please help me

EDIT:

Sorry I didn't add some examples, so here they are:

1.

```
a = sorted(a, key=lambda x: x.split("NR;")[-1].split[";"][0])
```

1. for item in a:
   b.append(re.search("(;NR;[0-9]*;)", str(item)))

Basically I tried the above and some variations above, I can't exactly remember all the code I tried.

Comment: What does your current code look like?

Comment: _"I've already tried hundreds of solutions"_. Could you post one as an example? Just to get us started :-)

Comment: Was something like `sorted(lst, key=lambda s: ''.join(re.findall(s, '\d')))` among those tried solutions?

Comment: How do you deal with strings without any number then?

Comment: Well, as a non-language specific solution you could loop through the array and map this regex to a new array to grab the numbers: `(?<=;)[0-9]+(?=;)` at each index. Then you can loop through the new array to sort/reorder each element in your original array according to the mapped numerical values of the new one.

Comment: Ok. Sorry I didn't write more, I'm realy stressed right now, because I have to complete several tasks at the same time. The most promissing solution I tried was:
new_list = re.split("(;NR;[0-9]*;)", list)
sorted_list = sorted(new_list, key=itemgetter(1))

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks for a full fledged solution without demonstrating any attempt at solving the issue.

Comment: The user did provide an attempt in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21681282/python-sort-list-by-regular-expression#comment32775668_21681282). Perhaps that should be edited into the question? I'm also fine with closing because the OP edited in the solution from @Ewan's answer as if it was the OP's own try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [1]: a = ['jhfewrgjhdfjhgsufgssdfjgh;NR;3243;fgjdsgfjsdfkjgdf', 'dsafjhsafjkhefhajwejh;NR;123;dfgdsrhgjhdfgjhdsfjhg']

In [2]: a.sort(key=lambda x: x.split(';')[2])

In [3]: a
Out[3]:
['dsafjhsafjkhefhajwejh;NR;123;dfgdsrhgjhdfgjhdsfjhg',
 'jhfewrgjhdfjhgsufgssdfjgh;NR;3243;fgjdsgfjsdfkjgdf']
```

As pointed out by @EMS below it is possible to split on `NR;` and use the first part of that if there is always a `NR;` present.

```
a.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split("NR;")[-1].split(";")[0]))
```

This sorts the list in order. If you wanted to create a copy of your list (to assign it a new variable) you can use `sorted`

```
b = sorted(a, key=lambda x: int(x.split("NR;")[-1].split(";")[0]))
```

End-to-end:

```
# Includes an entry without the `;NR;`
In [1]:     a = ['jhfewrgjhdfjhgsufgssdfjgh;NR;3243;fgjdsgfjsdfkjgdf', 'dsafjhsafjkhefhajwejh;NR;123;dfgdsrhgjhdfgjhdsfjhg', 'jhfewrgjhdfjhgsufgssdfjgh;fgjdsgfjsdfkjgdf']

# Remove any entry that doesn't have `;NR;` in it
In [2]:     a = filter(lambda x: ';NR;' in x, a)

# Sort with an integer version of the number found (rather than the string)
In [3]:     a.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split("NR;")[-1].split(";")[0]))

In [4]: a
Out[4]:
['dsafjhsafjkhefhajwejh;NR;123;dfgdsrhgjhdfgjhdsfjhg',
 'jhfewrgjhdfjhgsufgssdfjgh;NR;3243;fgjdsgfjsdfkjgdf']
```

Comment: Or `lambda x: x.split("NR;")[-1].split[";"][0]` if the condition is that there is always exactly one occurrence of `NR;` present, and that the number (possibly empty) immediately follows it up to the next `;`.

Comment: Sort() saves life and execution time (:

Comment: @obayhan - yes it does! Especially if you have large lists, stops the need for duplicating into memory.

Comment: @Ewan your soultion returns: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @user3293486 - I apologise, I had some `[]` where I should have had some `()`. Please try now.

Comment: @Ewan It's running now, but sorts by the first digit of number not the whole number

Comment: That's because it is using the number as a string, and sorting lexically. Convert it to an `int` first (assuming these numbers are always integers) and then it will sort numerically.

Comment: `a.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split("NR;")[-1].split(";")[0]))`

Comment: Yeah I came up with that solution, too. However this isn't working either, for somehow it still sees the rest of the text, which naturally can not be converted to integer

Comment: Can there be multiple occurrences of "NR;" in one entry? Can the "NR;" be followed by letters instead of numbers? If not, then what you claim cannot be possible. If so, then you continue changing the specification of the strings and it's not useful for us to help you until you know the full extent of all possibilities.

Comment: There can be only one occurance of ";NR;" in one entry and it is always follwed by numbers and then a ";" however not every entry contains ";NR;" those entries should not be sorted, but stay in the list

Comment: I don't know maybe because there can be ";" in what follows the number

Comment: @user3293486 - the `;` wont matter as we are splitting on that after the number and taking only the number itself (it would also error out saying it wasn't an `int`).

Comment: Hmm... thats weird, because your code does sort by the number, but as soon as I add the int() function it reports "invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'dfsdjgjk'" where 'dfsdjgjk is the beginning of the first element in the list.
Does it matter that there are ";" before ";NR;" as well?

Comment: What does the string element that contains `dfsdjgjk` look like?

Comment: One element in the list is always GUID;RandomText;NR;Counter;Checksum; and I want to sort the list by the counter

Comment: The GUID in that case was numbers and chars and began with 'dfsdjgjk' should have mention that, sorry

Comment: Ok, I know found out that the elements with containing no "NR" were the problem. I striped them from the list and treated them seperately and now your code does exactly what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting a list always accept a 'key' argument and you can pass an arbitrary function as key. In your case, the function should do these:

1. Find the part of the string after "NR;"
2. Find the initial part of THAT part, that comes before ";" and parse it as an integer.

Here is one method to do this

```
def func(st): # I am using your first string as a running example in this code
    nr_part = st.split("NR;")[1]  # returns "3243;fgjdsgfjsdfkjgdf"
    int_part = nr_part.split(";")[0] # returns "3243"
    return int(int_part)
```

Now, you can separate out strings cointaining "NR;" by using filter.

```
aa = filter(a, lambda x: "NR;" in x)
```

Finally, sorting the resulting list is simple

```
aa = ['jhfewrgjhdfjhgsufgssdfjgh;NR;3243;fgjdsgfjsdfkjgdf', 'dsafjhsafjkhefhajwejh;NR;123;dfgdsrhgjhdfgjhdsfjhg']
a.sort(a, key=func)  # in place sorting
```

Or

```
sorted(a, key=func)  # Return a new sorted list
```

A few caveats: You must ensure that your assumptions of "NR;<int>" regex should be satisfied by all strings in the list and int part of the string should not be large enough so that 'int()' casting does not result in overflow.

Comment: Seems plausible, however I can't make it work... possibly because some elements in my list do not contain ";NR;"?

Comment: What is the goal for sorting the entries that do not have `NR;` present?

Comment: @EMS The goal is to sort the entries with ";NR;" and leave the rest alone

Comment: Then you can filter the list first: `new_list = filter(old_list, lamba x: "NR;" in x)` and any of these solutions will work. Use a generator expression if it's a large thing and sort the entries as they are placed into the final array.

Comment: I've edited my response to add `filter`. Note that after sorting the "NR;" filtered list, you will need to write your own code to merge it with the remaining elements